# Create form on Mouse Down, set form as active and start dragging form when mouse moves

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for the super long title, I have a very specific issue.

**What I am trying to do is the following:**

When clicking on a button, when the mouse button is pressed down, I would like to:

1. Show a Form
2. Position the form exactly where I want. I want the title bar to be exactly where the mouse is.
3. Without releasing the mouse button, I want to start moving the mouse. I want to emulate having clicked on the title bar and started dragging the window.

I have it mostly working, but not the positioning of the window. I can still click and it creates the form but its positioned to where the top left corner of the form is where the mouse cursor is. If I try to move the window, I can, but when I move the mouse it only moves up and down and is restricting on the X axis of the screen.

**Here is some code that I am using:**

```
Form NewForm = new TestForm();
NewForm.TopLevel = true;
NewForm.Owner = MainForm;
NewForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;

// Calculate location ratios
float WidthRatio = (float)MouseCurrentPos.X / (float)TitleRect.Width;
int PosX = (int)(NewForm.Width * WidthRatio);
NewForm.SetDesktopLocation(Cursor.Position.X - PosX, Cursor.Position.Y); 
NewForm.Select();
NewForm.Activate();
```

**My main questions are:**

1. How can I position the new form on Mouse Down event, while still holding the mouse button down and allow the mouse to move and drag the window without it acting weird?
2. Is there an 'official' way of creating a form and setting it to "Drag Window from Title Bar" mode? Not sure what the official term is, but when you drag a form from the title bar. Right now my code works but it feels like it is accidentally working, not working in an official way.

Comment: Post *all* the code that reproduces the problem.  "acting weird" doesn't tell us what is wrong.  Clearly, you lose MouseMove events when the mouse goes over the new form.

Comment: _When clicking on a button, when the mouse button is pressed down_ After you have clicked the button the mousebutton is always up. Maybe you want to lookup something like 'move borderless form' for helpful code. But maybe not -- I really don't understand the question..

Comment: So basically your trying to create a preview type mode that becomes the active form when you move the mouse?